AsyncImage in SwiftUI View content of UITableViewCell flickers previous image
I have a UITableViewController to host an infinite scrolling list, because I wanted to experiment with UITableView performance versus any kind of SwiftUI implementation, especially when going over longer lists.
It works really well, except for the AsyncImage. As soon as I start re-using cells that have an image, I very briefly see a previous image that was loaded. I think it's because of AsyncImage being confused into being the same AsyncImage as before due to re-use until it gets it's updated Image (or has a cache miss and switches to ProgressView).
This is the condensed code of the CommunityMessageListViewController:
@MainActor
public class CommunityMessageListViewController: UITableViewController {
    private let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTableView()
        Task {
            await observe(buffer: messageBuffer)
        }
    }

    public override func tableView(
        _ tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: cellIdentifier,
            for: indexPath
        )

        cell.contentConfiguration = UIHostingConfiguration {
            buildView(for: indexPath)
        }
        .margins(.horizontal, 8)
        .margins(.vertical, 4)
        .background { Color.clear }

        return cell
    }

    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView.register(
            UITableViewCell.self,
            forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier
        )

        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.backgroundColor = .gray

        tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    }
}

I removed all code that doesn't seem to be relevant to the issue, since it's working fine in all other aspects
The SwiftUI cell looks (condensed) like this:
@MainActor
public struct CommunityMessageCell: View {
    private let screenInset: CGFloat

    public var body: some View {
        Group {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if let attachment = message.imageAttachment {
                    factory.buildMessageCellImage(
                        for: attachment.url,
                        screenInset: screenInset
                    )
                        .aspectRatio(Constants.imageRatio, contentMode: .fill)
                }
                factory.buildMessageCellContent()
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }.clipped()
            .background(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .cornerRadius(Constants.cornerRadius, antialiased: true)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.cornerRadius)
                    .inset(by: Constants.borderWidth)
                    .strokeBorder(
                        .gray,
                        lineWidth: Constants.borderWidth,
                        antialiased: true
                    )
            )
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top)
        .background(.clear)
    }
}

Finally the MessageCellImage:
@MainActor
public struct MessageCellImage: View {
    private let imageURL: URL
    private let screenInset: CGFloat

    public init(
        imageURL: URL,
        screenInset: CGFloat // The amount of pts of padding horizontally of the container
    ) {
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.screenInset = screenInset
    }

    public var body: some View {
        AsyncImage(url: imageURL) { image in
            image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
        }
        .frame(
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - screenInset * 2,
            height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - screenInset * 2) / Constants.imageRatio
        )
        .clipped()
    }
}

bonus points for somebody that gets me to get rid of the UIScreen.main.bounds hack 
I tried GeometryReader but it eats my layout...
How do I make sure that my SwiftUI View tree understands it's not showing the same cell with the same image but is a new cell showing a probably different image?

Update:
Here's a blog post that explains the issue much deeper:
https://lucasvandongen.dev/swiftui_uitableviewcell_reuse_id.php
It's probably a much better practice to set the id(:) on the whole SwiftUI View.

Original answer:
I just figured this one out myself when I was typing out the question, but I'll leave it here for posterity:
My first hunch "I think it's because of AsyncImage being confused into being the same AsyncImage as before due to re-use" proved to be correct, what SwiftUI needed was a way to identify the fact that the AsyncImage had in fact changed:
        AsyncImage(url: imageURL) { image in
            image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
        }
        .id(imageURL)

The flicker is now gone, either it shows me the correct cached image or the ProgressView when loading.
So summarized: SwiftUI Views encapsulated in UITableViewCells sometimes need a custom id to understand they actually changed when re-using cells/
